# How to make an eval command?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, eval

The code I currently have doesn't work.

```
  const args2 = message.content.split(" ")
 
  if (message.content.startsWith("d!eval")) {
    if(!message.author.id == "749092490556080158") return;
    try {
      const code = args2.join(" ");
      let evaled = eval(code);
      
 
      if (!typeof evaled == "string")
        evaled = require("util").inspect(evaled);
 
      message.channel.send(clean(evaled), {code:"xl"});
    } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    message.channel.send(err)
    }
  }
  });
```

Instead, it returns the error:

```
    at Client.<anonymous> (/home/runner/WorthySimplisticProblems/index.js:20:25)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Client.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (/home/runner/WorthySimplisticProblems/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/home/runner/WorthySimplisticProblems/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/runner/WorthySimplisticProblems/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/runner/WorthySimplisticProblems/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/home/runner/WorthySimplisticProblems/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/runner/WorthySimplisticProblems/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
(node:421) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
    at RequestHandler.execute (/home/runner/WorthySimplisticProblems/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (/home/runner/WorthySimplisticProblems/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:39:14)
(node:421) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:421) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I'm not sure how to fix it, if someone could leave a github link or something like that, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: what exactly do you want this to do?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me!

```
 if (message.content.startsWith("d!eval")) {
    if(!message.author.id == "749092490556080158") return;
    var result = message.content.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ")
        let evaled = eval(result);
        console.log(result)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to define the function clean().
Use this it would work properly as i know

```js
const args2 = message.content.split(" ")
 
  if (message.content.startsWith("d!eval")) {
    if(!message.author.id == "749092490556080158") return;
    try {
      const code = args2.join(" ");
      let evaled = eval(code);
      
 
      if (!typeof evaled == "string") evaled = require("util").inspect(evaled);
      message.channel.send(evaled, {code:"xl"});
    } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    message.channel.send(err)
    }
  }
  });
```